# Relationship between the Turing Machine and RAM Models

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Could you tell me which is the relationship between the Turing Machine and RAM Models??

Comment: I think I remember that if a RAM machine can solve a problem  $ O (f (n)) $ time then a Turing machine can solve the same problem in $ O (f (n^3)) $ time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random-access machine with unbounded indirection is equivalent to a Turing machine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine#Turing_equivalence_of_the_RAM_with_indirection). Informally speaking, both machines have the same computational capabilities.